# How/where to programmatically delete cookies to avoid a 403.14 Forbidden error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, http-status-code-403

I have an application that uses forms authentication. It also has a default document (directory browsing not needed).

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Access/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

At first, the login page displays as expected and authenticates after successful login. Then, the user clicks a redirect to leave the application for another domain.

Later, the user tries to re-enter the application but cannot navigate to the Login.aspx page without receiving the 403.14 Forbidden error. The following cookies are present:

```
".ASPXAUTH"
"ASP.NET_SessionId"
"domain.org"
```

If cookies are manually deleted using IE11's "Clear cookies for domain", the login page will load successfully. But deleting these cookies programmatically has no effect; the 403.14 error still occurs. How/where can one programmatically delete cookies to avoid the error?

Comment: I think you're looking for the wrong answer, something must be wrong with your authentication.   Only way to 'delete' a cookie is to set it to expire immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication cookies needed to be removed. Adding the following code just before the redirect worked:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```